# jQuery Drop Down Hover on Div (Not Just Link)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this slider to hover when you try to go to the div as well as I will be using this for a dropdown menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/ANFRD/263/

```
  <a href="#" id="toggleLink">Click Here</a>
  <div class="toggledDiv">This is the content of the toggled div</div>
  <div class="alwaysVisible">This is the content of the always visible div</div>
```

And the JS

```
var toggleState = true;
$('#toggleLink').hover(function () {
if (toggleState) {
    $('.toggledDiv').stop().animate({
        height: 80
    }, 500);
} else {
    $('.toggledDiv').stop().animate({
        height: 0
    }, 500);
}
toggleState = !toggleState;
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by using [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) on the `a.toggleLink` to show the div.  Then on [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) of the `toggleWrapper` I hide the div.  If you dont want to use a wrapping div (it prevents it from sliding up when you hover back over the `a.toggleLink` you can change `$('.toggleWrapper')` to `$('.toggledDiv')`

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/KWdaT/)

Side note, please note that I removed the ID and am using a class instead.I would recommend changing the style and using a class.

```
<div class='toggleWrapper'>
    <a href="#" class="toggleLink">Click Here</a>
    <div class="toggledDiv">This is the content of the toggled div</div>
</div>
<div class="alwaysVisible">This is the content of the always visible div</div>
```

Then change the style to:

```
.toggleLink{
  display:block;
  width:100%
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('a.toggleLink').mouseover(
    function () {
        $('.toggledDiv').animate({height: 80}, 500);
    }
);                 

$('.toggleWrapper').mouseleave(
    function(){
        $('.toggledDiv').stop().animate({height: 0}, 500);
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nix! :) Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle or my site. I could easily be missing something, I'm just pasting the CSS style into my CSS document though.

Comment: Did you try my fiddle link?

Comment: Sorry Nix but I can't get it to work, the fiddle link doesn't work for me. :( To clarify, I'm trying to get to be able to hover over the div and it stay down (for example I will be putting categories in there).

Comment: Thanks so much Nix! :D Do you know if there is anyway of preventing the dropdown from going up and down when you come back off the div back to the menu?

Comment: My fiddle shouldn't be doing that, I am wrapping the "menu, and the toggleDiv" so it should only collapse once you have left the wrapper.